# Hiding default gray column in datagridview winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to remove or hide winform's datagrid gray area when data is not avaiable?

Second this how to remove/hide the default gray column?

```
  dataGridView1.DataSource = oresult;
  dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible  = false;
  dataGridView1.Columns["AddedBy"].Visible = false;
  dataGridView1.Columns["AddmissionInClass"].Visible = false;
  dataGridView1.Columns["IsDeleted"].Visible = false;
  dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
```

I'm hiding useless columns like this but unable to find way to hide these.

[image]

Answer (score 215, accepted):

To hide first column you can set [`RowHeadersVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible.aspx) to false of your dataGrid

Answer (score 23):

Just set the Background-Color and the RowHeadersVisible-State of your DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Comment: Better value for BackgroundColor probably is System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window

Answer (score 9):

You need set properties for RowHeaderVisible (from gridview properties) to be false

Answer (score 4):

Just put this piece of code. Worked for me.

```
DataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
DataGrid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two approaches to do this:

1. Adding this line:

   ```
   dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
   ```

   to...

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
   }
   ```

   -OR-
2. From (Project's Properties) window change **True** to **false** like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete grid view column in column level and its not being reflected in grid view please follow as below:
We can't delete the column of grid view in column level.
So, delete the column's cell in row level (means in each and every row).

```
foreach (GridViewRow Row in this.searchResults.SearchResultGrid.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                    GridViewRow HeaderRow = this.searchResults.SearchResultGrid.HeaderRow;
                    HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DGV.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Although a few years have passed but I have reached it now...
I had to change it in all the DataGrids in all the project.
I make this in aApp.XAML

```
  <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
 <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
   </Style>
```

Comment: The question is about WinForms, not WPF