# How to hide the first index indicator column of DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't know what is the exact name of that column, please see my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: dgvDetails.RowHeadersVisible = False

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding default gray column in datagridview winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653306/hiding-default-gray-column-in-datagridview-winform)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```