# C# DataGridView unnecessary left hand column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm creating a DataGridView in limited space so I really don't need the leftmost column which doesnt contain anything but allows you to select the entire row when clicked on

Any ideas on how to remove it?

[image]

[image] what it should look like <-

Comment: This question has been answered [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15653436/12677784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the "empty column", you can set the `RowHeadVisible` property to `False`.